# Utilize Pandas built-in for aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there some builtin aggregation to Pandas (or NumPy?) I can use to optimize the line marked with `***` below?

```
    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> import pandas as pd
    >>>
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,21,4,5,3,3,5,653,2], 'B':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
    >>> steps = 3
    >>>
    >>> values = df.iloc[:,0]
    >>> current = values[-steps:]
    >>> old = values[:-steps]
*** >>> mean = np.array([old[i::steps].mean() for i in range(steps)]) ***
    >>> df.iloc[-steps:,0] = current - mean
    >>> df1 = df.iloc[-steps:]
    >>> df1
           A  B
    6    2.0  7
    7  641.0  8
    8   -1.5  9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could compute `mean` in a vectorized manner, which on account of the for-loop seems to be the bottleneck, like so -

```
mean = old.values.reshape(-1,steps).mean(axis=0)
```

For cases when the array size might not be divisible by `steps`, we could use `np.bincount` -

```
ids = np.arange(a.size)%steps
mean= np.bincount(ids, a)/np.bincount(ids)
```

Comment: Beautiful solution, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: When shape isn't easily dividable by `steps` I get an error in the form `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3025 into shape (1008)`. Do you know of an easy way to prepend my array with the first value until I get it `steps` aligned?

Comment: @JonasByström Added one solution for that. There are other ways, but the posted one seems to be the shortest to handle those cases.